# Exclude child elements from a table cell using tablesorter filter widget

Tags: jquery, filter, tablesorter

Is it possible to exclude child elements from a table cell using tablesorter filter widget?

I.e. if I type `Mia` in the filter box, I only want the second row to be shown. But the default behaviour of the filter widget is to search all content of the table cell, and because of that row 1 is also shown as `Mia` is also in `<div class="information">` in row 1.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                John
                <div class="information">
                    He is 25 years old and has a sister called Mia
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mia</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm using `$('table').tablesorter({ widgets: ['filter'] });` to initiate the tablesorter.

If it's not possible I have to place the additional information for each cell somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of the `textExtraction` function along with the `filter_useParsedData` option ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/708/)):

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    textExtraction: {
        0: function (node) {
            return $(node).contents().filter(function () {
                return this.nodeType === 3;
            }).text();
        }
    },
    widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
    widgetOptions: {
        filter_useParsedData: true
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked really well! =) Care to explain what is going on in the textExtraction function?

Comment: Okay, it was actually pretty straight forward when I looked into it a bit. Thanks again! :)